# how to share quicksight embeded dashboard with multiple clients

Tags: dashboard, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I would like to share an embeded quicksight dashboard with multiple clients.

I have set a big dashboard for the company to access the whole data.
The problem now is i would like to share it for each clients with their own data only.

I know i can filter rows with solutions like RLS based on a field containing the database name.
But i don't know what would be the best way to perform it ? (RLS is only an option here)

The second part of the problem.
i will have new client data included but what about sharing for new clients?
I need an automatic solution.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use row level security to allow access only to a subset of the data to either users or groups. To do this, create a permissions dataset that says who (user or group) can access which rows, then attach the permissions dataset via the Row-level security button.

For my use case, I create a Quicksight group for each customer account (with boto3 [create_group](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/quicksight.html#QuickSight.Client.create_group)), then add individual users to groups (with boto3 [create_group_membership](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/quicksight.html#QuickSight.Client.create_group_membership)). The group Name is the account id, since it won't change; the Description is the account name.

The permissions dataset specifies that members of a group can see the matching account. These values will be the same, since the group name is the account id. For example, this CSV says members of group `abc123` can see only rows where the `account_id` field is `abc123`:

```
account_id,GroupName
abc123,abc123
```

To add an account to Quicksight:

- create a Quicksight group for the account via [create_group](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/quicksight.html#QuickSight.Client.create_group)
- (re-)create the permissions dataset from the list of accounts in the database
- upload the permissions dataset to S3
- reingest the permissions dataset with [create_ingestion](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/quicksight.html#QuickSight.Client.create_ingestion)

To allow a user to access Quicksight data:

- create the Quicksight user via [register_user](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/quicksight.html#QuickSight.Client.register_user) with Quicksight
- add the user to account group(s) via [create_group_membership](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/quicksight.html#QuickSight.Client.create_group_membership)

See also Amazon's [row level security docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/restrict-access-to-a-data-set-using-row-level-security.html).